# How can I be sure who sees what post on Facebook when I'm restricting which lists see what I post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

Say I have several groups/lists of friends on Facebook.

- Group A is family
- Group B is co-workers from company B
- Group C is co-workers from company C
- Group D is friends from university
- Group E is a group I've only met online

A couple of friends are members of more than one group (e.g. we were colleagues at more than one company).

By default when I post, I post to all my friends *except* family, so that's groups B, C, D and E.

Now say I want to restrict a post further so that neither family nor co-workers from Company C see it.

Will the friend who's in both Groups B and C still see the post? Which group takes precedence, the included group or the excluded group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion filter is applied first, then members of the exclusion filter are removed from the post’s audience. The exclusion filter wouldn’t be of much use if it was overridden by the inclusion filter.

This is how **Friends Except Acquaintances** works, for instance. *Acquaintances* doesn’t get overridden by its superset *Friends*. The same goes for the *Restricted* group, which is applied implicitly to the exclusion filter of every non-**Public** post.

In your case, you would post to *Friends*. Then, in the **Except** list, you would put groups *A* and *C*.

Alternatively (and provided all your friends are in those 5 groups), you could post to groups *B*, *D* and *E*, keeping the same exclusion filter, and get the same result. The main reason you’d want to do this is if you want to hide those posts from future, uncategorized friends.

If you want to verify this, you can create a dummy post, then use Facebook’s **View As…** feature under your profile’s **…** menu:

[image: Gear Menu]

Then type in the name of a person in group *C*:

[image: View As…]